# CSS font-size not working

Tags: html, css, input

I'm trying to use font-size element but the size of the font is not changing correctly. All code return small text in text fields and selector:

The font size in the following selectors below remain small:

```
input[type=number] {
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:50px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:50px;
}

select {
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:50px;
}
```

Can I be pointed in the correct direction? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well so we can take a look.

Comment: Have you got any other CSS that maybe overrules these styles?

Comment: Have you tried putting `!important` after each `font-size` property? As @putvande mentioned, it's possible your `font-size` values are being overridden by a parent element.

Comment: I made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjwb5btw/) and it's working (but the input size you chose does not perfectly fit the font-size). Could you post all your code, maybe something is interfering.

Comment: Have you used 'F12' in Chrome to see which CSS is active? It is probably being overridden, even by a master page?!